# Updating PHP4 to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently managing a little database for a club and I'm starting to feel more and more pressure to update the thing to PHP5. The only thing is that I'm not quite a 100% sure on how to convert this structure without messing up the whole thing. (Or starting from scratch)

Could you guys tell me if this is easily editable/updatable or if I should redo everything? (The total file is 800 lines, so I hope to not have to redo it :P)

So I open the databse with:

```
//Database connection settings
$mysql_server = "localhost"; 
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass"; 
$mysql_database = "database";
//Connect using settings
$connection = mysql_connect("$mysql_server","$mysql_user","$mysql_password") 
  or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL server.");
$db = mysql_select_db("$mysql_database") 
  or die ("Unable to select requested database.");
```

Then I can create users with:

```
if($changeme ==1) //if user pressed save, then update table
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);           

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Members (name,) VALUES
        ('$name')") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //show end text
    echo "Edit complete!<br />
    <form><input type='button' onClick=\"parent.location='users.php'\" value='OK'></form>";

}else{//user didn't press save

    ?>
    <!--Edit form-->
    <form action="users.php?new=1&changeme=yes" method="post">
    Naam:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="79"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create">
    <input type='button' onClick="parent.location='users.php'" value='Back to list'>
    </form>
}
```

I left out everything but name to make it shorter, it has like 30 fields.

Next we can also edit the profiles like this:

```
if($changeme ==1) //if user pressed save, then update table
{
    $id    = $_POST['id']; //get ID from form
    $name = $_POST["name"];

    mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    //show end text
    echo "Edit complete!<br />
    <form><input type='button' onClick=\"parent.location='users.php'\" value='OK'></form>";
}else{//user didn't press save

    $id = $_GET['edit']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE id='$id'";
    $self = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($self)) {
        $name = $row["name"];

    }
    ?>
    <!--Edit form-->
    <form action="users.php?edit=<?php echo $id ?>&changeme=yes" method=post>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    Name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name ?>" size="79"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Change">
    <input type='button' onClick="parent.location='users.php'" value='Back to list'>
    </form>

    <?php
}//didn't press save
```

Comment: Given that the mysql_*() code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - yes, you need to rewrite your entire database interface from scratch. Blindly translating the queries from mysql_*() to PDO will not make anything better if you don't account for the injection problem.

Comment: It looks like it does need some refactoring, and it may be worth it to look into different PHP frameworks.

Comment: it's a small uni club, I'm not really afraid of SQL injections :P

Comment: You've never met a uni student who was a bit of a "prankster"?

Comment: The [mysqli](http://ca1.php.net/mysqli) functions work pretty much as a drop-in for the old mysql functions. If you just want something fast and dirty, I'd start there. If it's such a small project, starting from scratch may not be such a bad idea.

Comment: @miken32 MySQLi is only a drop-in replacement for `mysql_*()` up to the point where you have to change _all_ of the function arguments to include the link resource, and change any user functions the calls reside in to either pass the resource as a parameter or access it globally.

Comment: (that seems like quite a trivial change to me) - but then I tend to go for a minimal query approach